# Summarise open hours array to natural language string

Tags: php

I have a list of open and close timings saved in an array like this

```json
{
    "monday": {
        "working": "yes",
        "open": "09:00",
        "close": "17:00"
    },
    "tuesday": {
        "working": "yes",
        "open": "09:00",
        "close": "17:00"
    },
    "wednesday": {
        "working": "yes",
        "open": "09:00",
        "close": "17:00"
    },
    "thursday": {
        "working": "yes",
        "open": "09:00",
        "close": "18:00"
    },
    "friday": {
        "working": "yes",
        "open": "09:00",
        "close": "17:00"
    },
    "saturday": {
        "working": "yes",
        "open": "09:00",
        "close": "14:00"
    },
    "sunday": {
        "open": "00:00",
        "close": "00:00"
    }
}
```

I need to create a string that would most naturally describe the timings in one line.
So for the above the expected output is

```
$result = 'mon to wed and fri: 09:00 to 17:00, thu: 09:00 to 18:00, sat: 09:00 to 14:00';
```

if using `and` is difficult I can also use a `, (comma)` like this

```
$result = 'mon to wed, fri: 09:00 to 17:00, thu: 09:00 to 18:00, sat: 09:00 to 14:00';
```

The array is created to account for different conditions so a valid timing could also be
`mon to fri: 09:00 to 17:00`

I am confused how to get this done. I can iterate over the array and manually build something like that but is that a good approach.

As of now I have done something like this

```php
$openHoursReduced = [];
$openHoursJson = '{"monday":{"working":"yes","open":"09:00","close":"17:00"},"tuesday":{"working":"yes","open":"09:00","close":"17:00"},"wednesday":{"working":"yes","open":"09:00","close":"17:00"},"thursday":{"working":"yes","open":"09:00","close":"18:00"},"friday":{"working":"yes","open":"09:00","close":"17:00"},"saturday":{"working":"yes","open":"09:00","close":"14:00"},"sunday":{"open":"00:00","close":"00:00"}}';
$openHoursArray = json_decode($openHoursJson, true);
foreach ($openHoursArray as $dayOfWeek => $dayConfigs) {
    if(!empty($dayConfigs['working']) && $dayConfigs['working'] == 'yes'){
        $hoursStr = sprintf('%s to %s', $dayConfigs['open'], $dayConfigs['close']);
        $openHoursReduced[$hoursStr][] = $dayOfWeek;
    }

}
var_dump($openHoursReduced);
```

And the results I get are

```
array (size=3)
  '09:00 to 17:00' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'monday' (length=6)
      1 => string 'tuesday' (length=7)
      2 => string 'wednesday' (length=9)
      3 => string 'friday' (length=6)
  '09:00 to 18:00' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'thursday' (length=8)
  '09:00 to 14:00' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'saturday' (length=8)
```

Unsure how to go about creating the text representation.

What is the best approach here. Any suggestion is very helpful.

Thanks in  advance.

Comment: You don't need to hard-code your JSON as a string literal like: `$openHoursJson = '{"monday":{"working":"yes","open":"09:00","close":"17:00"}}';` - you can build a PHP array and use `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Of course, this is just to make it easy to copy the codes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way how to decide when to use **comma** and **and**.

- If you have one part, just take all.
- If you have only two parts, just concat with **and**.
- If you have more, concat all parts with **comma**, except for the last one. Pop it off and append with **and**.

```
$sentence  = '';
$partCount = count($parts);

if ($partCount === 1) {
    // only 1 part, we can take all
    $sentence = $parts[0];
} else if ($partCount === 2) {
    // tow parts, so we can use and
    $sentence = implode(' and ', $parts);
} else if ($partCount > 2) {
    // pop last part
    // concat all with comma
    // append last with and
    $lastPart = array_pop($parts);
    $sentence = implode(', ', $parts) . ' and ' . $lastPart;
}
```

## Examples

```
$parts = ['A'];
// A

$parts = ['A', 'B'];
// A and B

$parts = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
// A, B and C

$parts = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
// A, B, C, D, E and F
```